# Angular 1.5 get variable from menu and set it to true

Tags: angularjs

angular 1.5

I'm creating a menu that on ng-click= i am getting the variable and than on ng-class setting that variable to true for the menu and the content.

Goal is on click to add/remove an active class to the parent and to the content div.

can't get my head around this one

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
  <li class="animate" ng-class="{activelist: fonts ==!hidden }">
  <a ng-click="activeMenu('fonts')" class="nav-icon">
                         menu font
  </a>
</li>
  <li class="animate" ng-class="{activelist: edit ==!hidden }">
  <a ng-click="activeMenu('edit')" class="nav-icon">
                         menu edit
  </a>
</li>
<ul>
<div class="">
<div class="fonttext" ng-class="{activelist: fonts ==!hidden }"></div>
<div class="edittext" ng-class="{activelist: edit ==!hidden }" ></div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
var myapp = angular.module('app', []);

myapp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.activeMenu = function (menuvar){
//getting the variable that gets passed via func
$scope.variable = menuvar;

// set the variable to be true no working
$scope.menuvar  = true;

  }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable directly in `ng-click` to `true`. This variable can then be used in `ng-class` to dynamically add or remove classes. Here is an example:

```
<li class="animate" ng-class="{'activelist': fonts }">
    <a ng-click="fonts = !fonts" class="nav-icon"></a>
</li>
<li class="animate" ng-class="{'activelist': edit }">
    <a ng-click="edit = !edit" class="nav-icon"></a>
</li>
```

---

You can also set the variable in the controller:

HTML:

```
<li class="animate" ng-class="{'activelist': menu.fonts }">
    <a ng-click="switchMenu('fonts')" class="nav-icon"></a>
</li>
<li class="animate" ng-class="{'activelist': menu.edit }">
    <a ng-click="switchMenu('edit')" class="nav-icon"></a>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.menu = {};
$scope.switchMenu = function(selectedMenu) {
    $scope.menu[selectedMenu] = !$scope.menu[selectedMenu];
};
```

Comment: yes but that mean every ng-click will be different. I am trying to get a function so my HTML stays clean with 1 function instead for every menu item unquic. Also that sets it to true but after it is true I can't turn it off

Comment: this is great for small menu, but still the idea behide script is on function call how do I set variable to be true. My goal is on ng-click I can hide several menus and other show. So when I click on menu item, I may show only some children menu. and when I click on a child menu I want to hide some parent item. That's why I am trying to figure out how to pass a vairable in the function and set some to be true or false

Comment: I've added another solution, where the logic is in the controller. I would however advise against that solution - even with larger menu etc. You can easily generate large HTML code with `ng-repeat` and still controll it directly in the HTML. I'd recommend putting those values in a scope variable to prevent name collisions in the controller scope.

Comment: Yes, that is the perfect! that what I need.

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer, if you like to.